# why my function in react.js doesn t work in codepen?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

i'm new to react.js and try to figure out why my code doesn't run in codepen. Any ideas?https://codepen.io/thenewmech/pen/QWbJbva

```
function Person(){
  return(
    <div className="person">
      <h1>Alex</h1>
      <p>My age: 37</>
    </div>    
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Person />,document.querySelector('#p1'));
```

Comment: Typo: `</>` should be `</p>`. I suspect Babel fails to compile this somehow. Not sure why codepen provide any indication that there is an error. In jsfiddle I get `SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token [...]`.

Comment: You may want to try https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Thank you very much for your time